# How to avoid stepping into dll code file?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I was debugging my project, at some point I also need to debug dll file.
What I did, I locate source code file and open it and all thing went well.

But now, when I reach at the same point dll file automatically open.
How could I avoid this situation? it annoy me.

Comment: Can you modify the source of the other DLL?

Comment: dll were compiled in separte project. and placed into main project.
As project grow, i need to fix one issue, i locate the dll source file and open it in my mian project, and it works. but now every time when I debug my main project it automatically open dll source file.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way around it is to press F10 when you want to step over a method call.

Comment: i know F10. how can i avoid it.

Comment: I am using dll. But to debug that dll i opened the source file. but now every time it automatically open.

Comment: If the file opens, then there must be some function of that DLL you are stepping in. Yes, you should use F10. Otherwise, I think ppl don't understand what you mean by "how can i avoid `it`"!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From the menu, try Tools -> Options and then open the Symbols page under the Debugging folder.

There might be some symbol file added there you can remove.

Answer (score 0):

Under Tools->Options->Debugging, you should be able to select "Enable Just My Code", which *should* do what you want

Comment: I did it, but still have problem.